# VIM folds for Everything except Something

Tags: vim, folding

A code is over 2000 lines full of folds. I select a certain block in Visual mode to which I would like to start writing. However, things around the block, such as folds, hinder my writing, and I accidentally tend to modify them. Currently, I avoid such mistakes by writing the block in a separate vim. It is not a real solution, and it gets awkward with too many vim's open.

*How can I hide everything except the block in folds?*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do `zMzv` or `zMzO`.

`zM` closes all folds
`zv` makes the current line visible
`zO` opens all folds under cursor recursively up to root

(`O` in `zO` is the uppercase "oh" character, not zero `0`)

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you asked for, but might work...

Map this friend to something:

```
:vnoremap <Leader>za <Esc>`<kzfgg`>jzfG`<
```

I have it on leader => z (because it has to do w/ folding) => a (because it stands for "around")

Usage:

Select lines with V, hit leader z a.
Everything above and below will be folded.

Comment: Wow. That's perfect. Just want to mention that

`:nmap <silent><Leader>zs <Esc>zRzz`

is a nice way to unfold everything back